# Is it possible to have both orderBy and filter for the same table in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my table it works fine `orderBy` (descending and ascending). It looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped top-scroll__content">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="$ctrl.sorting('Name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="$ctrl.sorting('Type')">Occurence</th>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.alertsResponse | orderBy:$ctrl.sort.active:$ctrl.sort.descending track by $index">
            <td>{{rows.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{rows.Type}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I added a dropdown selector from whom I select a `type` and I want the table to show only the rows having the selected type.

The JS function works well, it returns the desired result in console and looks like this:

```
updateFilter(type) {
    debugger;
    if (type === "0") return this.alertsResponse;

    return this.alertsResponse.filter(function(item) {
        return item.Type === type;
    });
}
```

My problem comes when I want to add this functionality to the table. I tried to add the filer in the same place as `orderBy` but probably it is not the right way:

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.alertsResponse | orderBy:$ctrl.sort.active:$ctrl.sort.descending track by $index | filter:$ctrl.updateFilter(Type)">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to pass controller function in filter just pass drop down selector text in filter instead of drop down selector value

```
ng-model of drop down should be **type**
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.alertsResponse | orderBy:$ctrl.sort.active:$ctrl.sort.descending track by $index | filter:Type">
```

OR

You can filter your data by passing object in filter like

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.alertsResponse | orderBy:$ctrl.sort.active:$ctrl.sort.descending track by $index | filter:{Type:type}">
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [
      {Type:1, name:'Tom'},
      {Type:2, name:'Jerry'}, 
      {Type:2, name:'Dom'},
      {Type:1, name:'Apple'}
    ];
    
    $scope.type = "1";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<select ng-model="type">
 <option value="1">Tom</option>
 <option value="2">Jerry</option>
</select>


<table border="1" style="margin-top:20px">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th >Name</th>
        <th >Occurence</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="rows in rows | filter:{Type:type}">
            <td>{{rows.name}}</td>
            <td>{{rows.Type}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Use it like filter:{Type:type}

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.alertsResponse | orderBy:$ctrl.sort.active:$ctrl.sort.descending track by $index | filter:{Type:type}"> add this code and let me know if its working now or not

Comment: I added it, same result, no data in the table. Doesn't it need to be a connection between filter and the method `updateFilter()` ?

Comment: No it does not need any connection angular provides built in filters. I am adding a demo just check it.

Comment: your code is working, I'm trying to adapt mine to it :)

Comment: ckeck your variables Type (uppercase or lower case) and check ng-model variable name is correct 'type'

Comment: create a fiddle of your code and give me link of it i will fix it.

Comment: I moved it to a chat room, are you able to see it? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169235/discussion-between-dadsa-and-pavan-sikarwar